# Validate angular regex so so it doesn’t have info@, admin@, help@, sales@

Tags: angularjs, regex

I would like to block some kind of emails using angular ng-pattern

The emails below should not be valid

> info@anything.com
>
> admin@anything.com
>
> help@anything.com
>
> sales@anything.com

The regex below worked

```
^((?!info)(?!admin)(?!help)(?!sales)[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-])+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,63}$
```

But not as I expected because I wold like to allow i.e

> information@anything.com

How can I block the info@, admin@, help@, sales@?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may join the lookaheads into 1 and add `@` after the values to ensure you match the user part up to `@` (as  a whole):

```
/^(?!(?:info|admin|help|sales)@)[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,63}$/
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c8K4ZV/1)

The `(?!(?:info|admin|help|sales)@)` negative lookahead fails the match if, after the start of a string (`^`), there is `info@` or `admin@` or `help@`, or `sales@`.